# Rails, Capistrano 3 and SSH agent forwarding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ssh, proxy, capistrano

Initial state:

1) I have PC, which have access only to local server (ssh deployer@localserver is working, ssh git@github.com is not).

2) I have local server (mentioned above), which have access to Internet (ssh git@github.com is working)

3) I need to deploy my Rails apps from the PC using Capistrano through this local server.

I have read [SSH-agent-forwarding](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/ssh-agent-forwarding.html) topic and here is my situation:

[image]

What do I want:

I would like to have an ssh access from the PC to my VPS like this:

```
ssh ubuntu@ec2-...#.com.
```

How can I do it? Probably I need something in my ~/.ssh/config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution:

In ssh/config file we should put the following:

```
Host github.com
Hostname github.com
ProxyCommand ssh -q deployer@localservername nc -q0 %h 22
User git
```

Instead of github.com there can be another host or just (*):

```
Host *
ProxyCommand ssh ....
```

Also [this(transparent-multihop-ssh)](http://sshmenu.sourceforge.net/articles/transparent-mulithop.html) is very useful link regarding this issue.